# i want fadeOut my div after the time, in audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery

My English is not good, sorry.

I want to fadeOut my div after a specific time, in audio player.

I want to set time value, call from my div ul li.

Everything is ok if:
Put number Instead: **fa1**

```
var audio = document.getElementById("player");
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
var fa1 = $("#timevbfa ul:nth-child(1) li").text();
var timeSetfa1 = fa1;

var _currentTime = Math.round(audio.currentTime);
if (_currentTime === timeSetfa1) {
    $(".dofarsi").fadeOut();
}
}, false);
```

my html code:

```
<div id="timevbfa">
    <ul>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>22</li>
        <li>33</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dofarsi">Hello</div>
```

Comment: So what actually does happen? Do you get an error message? Or does it do something other than what you expected? Have you looked in the debugger to see what value `fa1` actually has? Is it what you expected?

Comment: @MattBurland fa1 is first li text=10

Comment: @ramin I think the problem could be with `_currentTime === timeSetfa1`.Try changing it to `_currentTime >= timeSetfa1`

Comment: @ramin are you sure about that? Did you actually _check_ it? Because you aren't selecting the first, you are selecting _all_ the `li` elements. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mktuy47L/ And you still haven't actually said what your code _actually_ does that is unexpected.

Comment: can you please add your complete code I cannot find the `player` element in your html block

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir I did what you said and fixed my problem. thanks

Comment: @MattBurland thanks for answer me

Comment: _currentTime === timeSetfa1 change to _currentTime == timeSetfa1 is correct.